# SQL: "... WHERE result<4.0" if 'result' is: "15.2","UNK","1.4"?

Tags: sql, casting

How can I make this select only the row with "1.4" if result has values "15.2","UNK","1.4"?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE result<4.0
```

(ideally something that works both for MSSQL and MySQL...)

Here is the 'result' column

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
  `result` varchar(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl` (`result`) VALUES ('15.2'),('UNK'),('1.4');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
    from tbl
    where 1 = case ISNUMERIC(result + 'e0') 
                   when 1 then case when CAST(result as float) < 4.0 
                                   then 1 
                                   else 0 
                              end 
                   when 0 then 0 
              end
```

Comment: @ajo: Modified my answer with a version that will work for MSSQL. MySQL does not have a built in ISNUMERIC.

Comment: @Joe why isnumeric(result + 'e0') rather than isnumeric(result)?

Comment: @ajo: `ISNUMERIC` by itself is flaky. Things like `ISNUMERIC('$')`, `ISNUMERIC('+.')` and `ISNUMERIC('2e5')` all evaluate to 1. The `+ 'e0'` protects against those cases. You can also use `+ '.0e0'` if you want to check for only integers.

Comment: could one do something like `select * from tbl where case isnumeric(result)=1 then result<4.0 else 0=1 END`; ?? although I haven't worked out the details yet...

Comment: @ajo: I've changed my answer to reflect this. This is actually preferable to my previous version.

Comment: that's looks better. Do you need the `where 1= ...` ?
Do you get it working with `where 4.0< case ...` ?

Comment: @ajo: The syntax is ugly but you need to write it this way. The nested case statements ensure evaluation of the comparisons in the correct order (i.e., ISNUMERIC check must occur before attempting to CAST the result.)

Comment: @joe-stefanelli: I was thinking along the lines of `... where 4.0 > case when isnumeric(result+'e0')=1 then CAST(result as float) else 999.9 end` ??

Answer (score 0):

@ajo, if you want to select only rows with "1.4" if result has values "15.2","UNK","1.4", what about using Like??

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE result like '1.4'

Comment: He wants to perform a numeric comparison of `result < 4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ISNUMERIC(result) = 1 AND result < 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl 
 WHERE CAST(NULLIF(result, 'UNK') AS DECIMAL(9, 4)) < 4.0;
```